# Encode and send an XDR struct over a TCP socket (C - Linux)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, xdr

I have to ask the question below:

I have to send the following XDR message:

```
struct Responde{
 float numbers<>;
 bool end;
}
```

I know how to enconde array (xdr_array) and bool (xdr_bool) but how can I:

1) Encode the struct?
2) Send the struct over a socket?

Thanks to all, but I don't know XDR and I have to use it. Thanks again.

N.b.: How title shows I refer to C language and Linux environment.

Comment: What is `<>`, please?

Comment: It means that this is a variable-length array with maximum 2^32-1 element on it

Comment: You might want to read here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1435/6m7rrfn7f/index.html (scroll down to "Passing Complex Data Structures")

Comment: `<>`is not C. In C it would be `[]` and only be allowed for the last member in a `strcut`.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible solution would of course be to use the `rpcgen` tool to compile the XDR definition to C code, which you can then compile and used in your C application. But if you do not want introduce this dependency into your project, you can of course write the serialization code by hand.

[RFC 1831](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1831) will give you a detailed description of how such a structure is serialize but here is what you need to know for your example:

- All number in XDR are encoded in big-endian order.
- All fields in a structure are aligned to 4 bytes and the fields are concatenated in the order they are declared.
- A `float` encodes a number as a 32-bit floating point number.
- The variable length array of floats is encoded as a 32-bit integer with containing the number of elements followed by the float numbers.
- A `bool` encodes a boolean value as a 32-bit integer where a true value is encoded as the number `1` and a false value is encoded as the number `0`.

For example, if your struct was filled with 3 floats and the value true, you would get the following byte stream:

```
00 00 00 03  xx xx xx xx  yy yy yy yy  zz zz zz zz  00 00 00 01
```

Where the sequences of `x`, `y` and `z` are the floating point numbers.